# in a method which produces lazy list, what happens if i return nothing?

Tags: c#

it seems this code is valid. I am wondering what if `getTest(1)`

```
    IEnumerable<int> getTest(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
            yield return 1;
        else
            ;
    }
```

Comment: It will not return any item (i.e. the enumerable sequence will have length 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will return an empty but non-null `IEnumberable<int>`.

Once you've marked a method as an iterator (by using `yield` anywhere in the method), it can execute **zero or more** `yield return`s to return data in the sequence.

In fact, the simplest way to get an empty IEnumberable is `IEnumerable<T> Empty() { yield break; }`.
Or just call `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`.

Comment: i had thought `yield return` was a phrase syntax... never expected that i can use `yield` + `break` or other command.

Comment: `yield break;` is the only other option. It immediately exits the method; equivalent to `return;` in a normal method.

Answer (score 1):

It just returns an empty, although fully "valid", enumerable. Everything went exactly as expected.